# Why my tomcat works differently if started from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I have just installed tomcat6 on Linux Mint
If I start Tomcat using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

I can see the welcome page on localhost:8080/
If I start tomcat using the eclipse IDE I cannot see the welcome page 
(but I am able to run and deploy application from the IDE)

since I am new to tomcat I couldn't see the difference.
Is tomcat using a different run environment when started from Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Eclipse uses the tomcat binaries only and recreates the configuration, webapp structure etc under you workspace metadata and executes your Web app by publishing into that. It does not carry over the webapps folder from tomcat installation.

Check `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0` to find your eclipse driven tomcat deployment.